# node-forever json config support all options?

Tags: json, node.js, forever

I tried to use json config to run forever, but some config seems not work. I wonder whether my code is wrong, or it only supports `--xxx` commands like `--minUptime`, except `-xxx` commands like `-m`.

```
.
├── forever
│   └── proConfig.json
└── test_debug.js

// config.json
{
  "append": true,
  "watch": true,
  "script": "test_debug.js",
  "minUptime": "100ms",
  "spinSleepTime": "10000ms",
  // -------------------------
  "MAX": 10,
  "LOGFILE": "forever.log",
  "OUTFILE": "out.log",
  "ERRFILE": "err.log"
}
```

Command:

```
forever start forever/proConfig.json
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you should check the command line usage. It should be below command:

```
forever start forever/proConfig.json
```

Secondly, forever does not support `minUptime`, `spinSleepTime`, .... in the configuration file. Please try to add it to the command:

```
forever start --minUptime 1000 --spinSleepTime 1000 forever/proConfig.json
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed the `start`.

Comment: Hi Deng, if my answer in useful for you, could you mark it is the useful answer?